# MySQL Connector not Working: NO module named Connector

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, sublimetext3, mysql-connector

OS: Ubuntu 17.10
Python: 2.7

**SUBLIME TEXT 3:**

I am trying to **import mysql.connector**,

**ImportError: No module named connector**

Although, when i try import mysql.connector in python shell, it works.

Earlier it was working fine, I just upgraded Ubuntu and somehow **mysql connector** is not working.

I have tried reinstalling **mysql connector using pip and git both.**

Still no luck.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see currently connector version for Ubuntu 17.10.
[image]

Have you tried alternative connections?

Hope it will help: 
    **http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html**

Answer (score 0):

I am now using Python 3.6, mysql.connector is working for me best.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04